# CableReady Stimulus Reflex: redis webpacker rails lost connection. Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could anybody help me with that?
i'm using cableready with stimulus reflex
that link won't help along very much .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eK1CM0MBF64&list=PLjItgYqIzJ9VHPdLo6ye9-2QkcTEeUEAg

i called the following:

bundle add stimulus_reflex &&
rails stimulus_reflex:install

would be happy to know your solution...

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\programming\bananagarden1\bananagarden05>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.2.2 (ruby 2.7.2-p137) ("Fettisdagsbulle")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 30660
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/gardens" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-03-08 14:18:05 +0100
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-03-08 14:18:05 +0100
   (1.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by GardensController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering gardens/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-03-08 14:18:05 +0100
  Garden Load (10.4ms)  SELECT "gardens".* FROM "gardens"
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  ↳ app/views/gardens/index.html.erb:16
  Rendered gardens/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 29.7ms | Allocations: 9633)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 85.6ms | Allocations: 20599)
Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 74.2ms | ActiveRecord: 18.1ms | Allocations: 26219)


#<Thread:0x000000000dc37d48 C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:150 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        32: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        31: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        30: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:354:in `establish_connection'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:304:in `connect'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `connect'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each_with_index'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:192:in `block in connect'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:154:in `connect_addrinfo'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': A blocking operation is currently executing. - connect(2) would block (IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable)
        32: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        31: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        30: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:354:in `establish_connection'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:304:in `connect'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `connect'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each_with_index'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:192:in `block in connect'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:153:in `connect_addrinfo'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:156:in `rescue in connect_addrinfo': Redis::TimeoutError (Redis::TimeoutError)
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:348:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:367:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        32: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        31: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        30: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:354:in `establish_connection'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:304:in `connect'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `connect'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each_with_index'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:192:in `block in connect'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:154:in `connect_addrinfo'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:1214:in `connect_nonblock'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:1214:in `__connect_nonblock': A blocking operation is currently executing. - connect(2) would block (IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable)
        32: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        31: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        30: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        29: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        28: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        27: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:354:in `establish_connection'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:304:in `connect'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `connect'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each_with_index'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:190:in `each'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:192:in `block in connect'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:153:in `connect_addrinfo'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:156:in `rescue in connect_addrinfo': Redis::TimeoutError (Redis::TimeoutError)
        26: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:154:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
        25: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:80:in `listen'
        24: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:81:in `without_reconnect'
        23: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:74:in `with_reconnect'
        22: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        21: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:75:in `block in with_reconnect'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:83:in `block in listen'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2325:in `subscribe'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `synchronize'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in synchronize'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:2326:in `block in subscribe'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis.rb:3507:in `_subscription'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:14:in `subscribe'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:44:in `subscription'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:144:in `call_loop'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:294:in `with_socket_timeout'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:111:in `connect'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:313:in `with_reconnect'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in connect'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:348:in `establish_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.2.5/lib/redis/client.rb:367:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

Comment: production.rb   config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/1") }

Comment: cable.yml development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: bananagarden05_development

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: bananagarden05_production